# Vue.JS Google Oauth login without triggering consent dialog in blank browser window?

Tags: vue.js, google-oauth

I'm researching the ability of using Google Oauth in an PWA Vue Application running on Android.

I found following options to implement the Google Oauth for the PWA running on Android:

- Google Consent rendered in blank system browser window ( Not Preferred )
- Implement Google Sign In SDK natively
- Leverage InAppBrowser feature with Cordova

Is there another option which I missed?

Thanks

The requirement is:

- Oauth with PWA running on Oauth without invoking the system browser